# Copying a portion of a footnote

Tags: vba, ms-word

In a Word file I need to copy only a portion of a footnote, let's say from char 2 to 8. The following code doesn't work.

```
Dim rng As Range
    
Set rng = ActiveDocument.Footnotes(1).Range.Duplicate
rng.SetRange(2, 8)  'compilation error, also those indexes refer to the main story
Set rng = rng.Document.Range(2, 8) 'compile, but those indexes refer to the main story
rng.Copy
```

`ActiveDocument.Footnotes(1).Range.Start` is 2. But when you set the Range to 2 it points to the main story.

How can I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Footnotes(1).Range
With Rng
  .Start = .Start + 2
  .End = .Start + 6
  MsgBox .Text
End With
End Sub
```